# Nested Flexbox Flex-Basis Not Working in Chrome or Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opera, flexbox

I have a row which is a `flexbox` filled with 3 columns which are also flexboxes. One of the columns is taller than the others so the shorter ones stretch to match it's height. However when I set `flex-direction: column` on the columns and fill one with elements with percentage based flex-basis it doesn't work in Chrome or Opera.

It works in Firefox and IE. It also works if I set a specific height on the column but I can't do that. I also don't want to use the `flex-grow` property to try and do this because the size would change if you add or take away elements. Does anyone know a workaround to make this work in Chrome and Opera?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-1">
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
  </div>
  <div class="column col-2">
    <div class="cell cell-1">1</div>
    <div class="cell cell-2">2</div>
    <div class="cell cell-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-3">
    3
  </div>
</div>

.row {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
}
.col-1 {
  flex: 0 1 16.666%;
}
.col-2 {
  flex: 0 1 33.333%;
}
.col-3 {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}
.cell {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px;
}
.cell-1 {
  flex: 0 1 16.666%;
}
.cell-2 {
  flex: 0 1 33.333%;
}
.cell-3 {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGZNjY

Comment: Looks like a webkit bug. Not same with this, but probably with same cause of trouble: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341310.